# Can person commit Brahminicide without killing a Brahmana?

Tags: sin, brahmins

Brahminicide or Brahmanahatya is is considered a very heinous crime. Can a person commit Brahmanahatya without killing a Brahmin? People said that it is possible without even killing a Brahmin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Manu Smriti 11.54. Killing a Brahmana, drinking (the spirituous liquor
> called) Sura, stealing (the gold of a Brahmana), adultery with a
> Guru’s wife, and associating with such (offenders), they declare (to
> be) mortal sins (mahapataka).
>
> **11.55. Falsely attributing to oneself high birth, giving information to the king (regarding a crime), and falsely accusing one’s teacher,
> (are offences) equal to slaying a Brahmana.**

So, if someone commits any of the sins mentioned in the verse 11.55 then they have committed a sin that is equal to killing a Brahmin.

Comment: How does giving information to king becomes a sin? What's the logic behind it?

Comment: Giving false information to the king probably about a crime as a witness is a sin @MaruthiEranki